# Simple iPhone motion detect

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, core-motion

I need to detect when the gyroscope / accelerometer is activated a certain amount. Basically to detect when there is movement of the device. I don't know anything about Core Motion.

Maybe someone can direct me to a starters tutorial or something.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you have to use Core Motion. The good news is that it is not that hard to use for your problem domain. Start reading the [Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html) especially the section Handling Processed Device-Motion Data. If you are just interested in knowing **that** a slight motion was made, as you stated, you can omit rotation handling and narrow signal processing on CMDeviceMotion.userAcceleration. This is because every rotation results in accelerometer signals as well.

Create a [CMDeviceMotionHandler](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009670-CH1-SW25) as described in [startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CMMotionManager/startDeviceMotionUpdatesToQueue:withHandler:)
Your CMDeviceMotionHandler should do something like:

```
float accelerationThreshold = 0.2; // or whatever is appropriate - play around with different values
CMAcceleration userAcceleration = deviceMotion.userAcceleration;
if (fabs(userAcceleration.x) > accelerationThreshold) 
    || fabs(userAcceleration.y) > accelerationThreshold
    || fabs(userAcceleration.z) > accelerationThreshold) {
    // enter code here
}
```

Basically that's it. Bear in mind that every acceleration will have a counterpart. That means, if you apply a force to move (i.e. accelerate) the device to the right, there will be a counterpart for deceleration to stop the motion and let that the device rest at the new position. So your `if` condition will become true twice for every single motion.

Comment: The link you gave is excellent! Even though I've been searching on motion readings, and read all relevant class references - I just couldn't a find a summary like that - thanks!

Comment: Thank you for explaining in a simple and easy to understand way :)

Comment: This link is dead "Handling Processed Device-Motion Data" Can you please update the link?

Comment: At the time of this comment, you can find a cached copy of that article [here](http://nathanmock.com/files/com.apple.adc.documentation.AppleiOS6.0.iOSLibrary.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MotionEvents/MotionEvents.html).

Answer (score 2):

In `viewDidAppear`, become the first responder:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

And make sure you can be first responder:

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}
```

Then you can implement the motion detection.

```
- (void)motionEnded:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (event.subtype == UIEventTypeMotion){
        //there was motion
    }
}
```