# How to notice a quick forward motion with didAccelerate deprecated?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, accelerometer, motion

What i want to do is read the acceleration.y and do something like:

```
if (acceleration.y > 0.8) {
   // Do something
}
```

As didAccelerate is deprecated I wonder how to get the y-value:

```
motionManager = [[[CMMotionManager alloc] init] autorelease];
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = kUpdateInterval;

if (motionManager.accelerometerAvailable) {
    [motionManager startAccelerometerUpdates];
}
else {
    //this device doesn't have accelerometer notice somewhere??
}

- (void)startAccelerometerUpdates {
 // READ Y-VALUE?????
}
```

I want to use raw accelerometer data so the app also works on 3GS. Is it possible to read the Y-value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: the answer below is deprecated, check [these posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742531/why-is-accelerometerdidaccelerate-deprecated-in-ios5) for the right way.

---

Old answer:

Use a UIAccelerometer singleton instance for this, for example in your AppDelegate

```
//in your launching method
    UIAccelerometer * accel = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
    accel.delegate = self;

//delegate method:
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration{
    // use the y-property of the acceleration
}
```

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Just curious, what scared you away from posting some info about the up to date solution ;) I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the [CMMotionManager class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMMotionManager) and search section named "Handing Motion Updates at Specified Intervals". In the "Accelerometer" bullet, it says

> Set the accelerometerUpdateInterval property to specify an update interval. Call the startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:withHandler: method, passing in a block of type CMAccelerometerHandler. Accelerometer data is passed into the block as CMAccelerometerData objects.

[CMAccelerometerData](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMAccelerometerData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/CMAccelerometerData) has a reference to CMAcceleration which is a struct that holds per axis acceleration.