# What replaces the iOS 5 deprecated accelerometer:didAccelerate?

Tags: ios5, deprecated, core-motion, accelerate-framework

Hmmm ... I am behind the times and trying to port over some old code to a new application and the accelerator delegation is deprecated.  There must be a replacement.  Please point me to the docs and get me jump started.

Comment: You guys are ambiguous, vague and rhetorical for closing this question.  It received a proper answer, so I don't understand your assessment.  If your goal is to discourage questions -- it is working.

Comment: Mobibob is right, I don't ask questions on here anymore, people just down vote and complain, if you don't like it you don't have to read it.  These questions are still helping people.

Comment: If the guys who closed this have difficulties to tell what is being asked they probably should take some Englisch lessons. It seems their goal is to discourage questions. Unacceptable!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The accelerometer was replaced by the Core Motion framework. Here are the docs: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CoreMotion_Reference/_index.html

You may also find this answer helpful:
[Why is accelerometer:didAccelerate: deprecated in IOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6742531/why-is-accelerometerdidaccelerate-deprecated-in-ios5)

Comment: Even when the question was closed. The answer is useful and I'm glad it exists. I really don't understand why it is closed.