# UIAccelerometer is Deprecated ios7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

how to use in ios7    UIAccelerometer

```
- (void)setupAccelerometer
    {
      UIAccelerometer *accelerometer = [UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer];
      accelerometer.updateInterval = 10.0f / 30.0f;
      accelerometer.delegate = self;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20340384/how-to-replace-uiaccelerometer-with-cmmotionmanager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can still use it... but the new way is to use [CMMotionManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/coremotion/reference/cmmotionmanager_class/index.html)

Comment: how to use in ios7 i d'not know can you explane me

Comment: its very similar to UIAccelerometer, just check the documentation i've linked in the answer now

Answer (score 8):

```
    // Configure Core Motion for getting Accelerometer data
//=========================================================

self.motionManager = [[CMMotionManager alloc] init];
if ([self.motionManager isAccelerometerAvailable]) {

    // Accelerometer is vailable. Configure to get acceleration

    [self.motionManager setAccelerometerUpdateInterval:(1.0 / 15)];

    [self.motionManager startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue] withHandler:^(CMAccelerometerData *accelerometerData, NSError *error) {

       // Your own code here

    }];
```

For more information, You can refer the Apple documentation right here :

[CoreMotion](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMotion/Reference/CMMotionManager_Class/index.html)